# cygwin open current folder from webstorm 9

Tags: cygwin, webstorm

I have set my shell as cygwin instead of the cmd.exe in Windows 8 using WebStorm 9 IDE.

But it opens the console at the default path `~`, how can I somehow specify it to open the current IDE root folder? Is it possible to send any parameter or something?

Comment: I didn't find any solution nor workaround yet.

Comment: The answer here should work for webstorm too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972081/open-cygwin-command-in-specified-directory-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer found there (thanks to @aikeru)

[Open Cygwin command in specified directory on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972081/open-cygwin-command-in-specified-directory-on-windows)

Basically just set the shell path to:
`your_cygwin64_path\bin\env.exe CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash -l`

*And make sure that you don't use a `cd` command from your `.bashrc` as well.*

Comment: I just get `java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY`

Comment: Happens sometimes to me as well for no reason, try restarting the IDE.

Comment: Happened to me even after a restart.  I think the answer may no longer be relevant for the current version of Webstorm/Cygwin.