# Open Cygwin command in specified directory on windows

Tags: cygwin, phpstorm

I use phpstorm and it's terminal facility.

In terminal section I typed `F:\Projects\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -` so it uses Cygwin as terminal. But it opens it in home folder. Is it possible to open it in different folder? By typing a command or by doing something else.

Because I have a folder called F:\Projects\Local in this folder I have vagrant and I want to open phpstorm, open terminal within php storm and just type vagran up. I don't want to open cgywin again.

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to open Cygwin with Mintty in the project directory then you can execute the command:

```
F:\Projects\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash -l
```

This will avoid automatically changing to the home directory. See https://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#Starting_in_a_particular_directory for more information on this command.

If you want to use the embedded PhpStorm terminal, then you can modify the Shell path in the terminal settings. Open `File > Settings... > Tools > Terminal`. Replace the shell path with `F:\Projects\cygwin64\bin\env.exe CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash -l`. You may need to restart PhpStorm after this change.

Note: this is assuming that your Cygwin Root Directory is `F:\Projects\cygwin64\`.

Comment: `cygwin64\bin\env.exe CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash -l` LIFE SAVER!!! :D Thanks man!

Comment: Don't forget to add quotes around initial command: `"F:\Projects\cygwin64\bin\env.exe" CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash -l`

Comment: You could use `/bin/zsh` instead to enable all those pretty babun features.

Answer (score 4):

For whome the above way ain't work anymore, like in PhpStorm v. 2016.3. The shell path have to be enclosed in quotes

```
"C:\Users\MyUser\.babun\cygwin\bin\env.exe" CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/zsh.exe
```

Comment: I have a space in my username so this helped.  I do get a % symbol in the terminal when I fire it up but its usable.

Comment: plus one! , this is a life saver

Answer (score 1):

For the PhpStorm that I'am using (v10.0.4) in Windows 10 I use this command works:

```
D:\tools\.babun\cygwin\bin\env.exe CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash.exe
```

I'm using [Babun](http://babun.github.io/) which installs the [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) in `D:\tools\.babun\cygwin`.

Comment: Tried on PHPStorm 2016.2.1 on Win 10 and got no luck. Error `java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY`. Thoughs?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206317869--Terminal-How-to-integrate-with-babun-cmder I tried this, but result is the same